# Adding a webserver to eth2wifi example for ESP32

Tags: wifi, esp32, web-services, ethernet

I am interested in using [ESP32-EVB](https://www.olimex.com/Products/IoT/ESP32/ESP32-EVB/open-source-hardware) from Olimex to run the [eth2wifi](https://github.com/espressif/esp-iot-solution/tree/master/examples/eth2wifi) from esp-iot-solution, using the wifi softap data forwarding demo.

If I correctly understand the code, it just moves packets from ethernet to wifi and viceversa. I would like also to export a webpage for controlling the relays, but it is not clear to me if this is doable with the proposed approach. If the board keeps forwarding packages without any check, how could those packages be sent to the embedded webserver?

Do you know any example or document that explains how to bridge wifi and ethernet while having a working webserver for implementing a REST api? I do not need NAT, but if examples based on NAT exists, they are acceptable.